# Maven package issue with surefire in php project

Tags: php, maven, phpunit, surefire

I'm trying to run a package command on my php project, but I'm getting an error related to surefire reports.
As you can see in the log, it's related to the phpunit test output...
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException:
    -no output-
    in file: C:\Users\Develop\adc\src\test\php\org\adc\apptest.php

Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong??..

Here I attach the hole "mvn package -e" command log:

```
C:\Users\Develop\adc>mvn package -e
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Sample PHP 5 web project 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-php-plugin:2.0-SNAPSHOT:set-sources (default-set-sources-1) @ adc ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-plugin-plugin:2.9:descriptor (default-descriptor) @ adc ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ adc ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Develop\adc\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-php-plugin:2.0-SNAPSHOT:resources (default-resources) @ adc ---
[INFO] Unpacking dependencies
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ adc ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Develop\adc\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-php-plugin:2.0-SNAPSHOT:testResources (default-testResources) @ adc ---
[INFO] Unpacking dependencies
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-php-plugin:2.0-SNAPSHOT:test (default-test) @ adc ---
[INFO]
-------------------------------------------------------
T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\Develop\adc\target\surefire-reports
[ERROR] Testcase: apptest.php fails.
[ERROR] See log: C:\Users\Develop\adc\target\surefire-reports\apptest.txt
[ERROR] Testcase: apptest.php fails.
[ERROR] See log: C:\Users\Develop\adc\target\surefire-reports\apptest.txt
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 24.101s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Feb 25 20:16:05 ART 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.phpmaven:maven-php-plugin:2.0-SNAPSHOT:test (default-test) on project a-don
de-comemos:
[ERROR] -no output-
[ERROR] in file: C:\Users\Develop\adc\src\test\php\org\adc\apptest.php
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.phpmaven:maven-php-plugin:2
.0-SNAPSHOT:test (default-test) on project adc:
-no output-
in file: C:\Users\Develop\adc\src\test\php\org\adc\apptest.php
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java
:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java
:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)

        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException:
-no output-
in file: C:\Users\Develop\adc\src\test\php\org\adc\apptest.php
        at org.phpmaven.plugin.build.PhpTest.executeTest(PhpTest.java:443)
        at org.phpmaven.plugin.build.PhpTest.doTesting(PhpTest.java:313)
        at org.phpmaven.plugin.build.PhpTest.execute(PhpTest.java:271)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: org.phpmaven.plugin.php.PhpErrorException:
-no output-
in file: C:\Users\Develop\adc\src\test\php\org\adc\apptest.php
        at org.phpmaven.plugin.build.PhpTest.executeTest(PhpTest.java:438)
        ... 23 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.adc</groupId>
    <artifactId>adc</artifactId>
    <packaging>php</packaging>
    <name>Sample PHP 5 web project</name>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.phpmaven</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-php-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <reportPlugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.phpmaven</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-php-plugin</artifactId>
                            <reportSets>
                                <reportSet>
                                    <reports>
                                        <report>phpdocumentor</report>
                                    </reports>
                                </reportSet>
                            </reportSets>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.10</version>
                            <reportSets>
                                <reportSet>
                                    <reports>
                                        <report>report-only</report>
                                    </reports>
                                </reportSet>
                            </reportSets>
                        </plugin>
                    </reportPlugins>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.phpunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>phpunit5</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are currently still bugs and false reports with some version. Use the following command "mvn -DflushPHPOutput=true test" to see the underlying error. Maybe there is something wrong within the test case php itself.

The archetypes are not ok for some version of phpunit. However looking at the php output should help.

Comment: it is now fixed. Because you are using the snapshot it now works (bugfixes in phpunit were done in the last 2 weeks).